# imagick , page break in pdf in php imagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

i am using php imagick to create a image and than convert to pdf. using php imagick. i coded this:

```
    $image = new Imagick();
    $height = 800; //height of the page;
    $image->newImage(794, $height, "#f5f5f5");
    $image->setImageFormat("jpg"); 
    $card = new Imagick('card.jpg'); ; //get single card 

    $l_align = 190; //left alignment
    for($i=0; $i < 4; $i++)  //for creating multiple cards on a page
    {
        $image->compositeImage($card, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,10, ($l_align*$i)+10);
        $image->compositeImage($card, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 390, ($l_align*$i)+10);
    }
    $image->setResolution(72, 72);
    $image->resetIterator();
    $combined = $image->appendImages(true);


    $image->setImageFormat("pdf");
    $combined->writeImages( 'card.pdf', true );
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="card.pdf"');

    echo file_get_contents('card.pdf');
```

and get something like this [image]
in pdf format . Now i want to page break after every 6 cards print in pdf . i am using imagick . please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong function for adding images as new pages. You should be using [addImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.addimage.php) which adds the new image as a separate page, rather than append which just tacks them onto the bottom of the current image.

An example of this working is:

```
$combined = null;

$images = [
    '../../../images/Source1.jpg',
    '../../../images/Source2.png',
];

foreach ($images as $image) {
    if ($combined == null) {
        $combined = new Imagick(realpath($image));   
    }
    else {
        $card = new Imagick(realpath($image)); ; //get single card 
        $combined->addImage($card);
    }
}

$combined->setImageFormat("pdf");
$combined->writeImages( './card.pdf', true );
```

btw there is weird stuff going on in your code example - you're only even attempting to add one image, and what is 'resetIterator' doing in there?